# Can I have a different controller called based on the value of request parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, model-view-controller

I designed BoardController for making boards, and FirstBoardController for FirstBoard implemented by inheriting this Board entity.

```java
@Entity
public class Board{
  protected Long id;

  protected String name;

  protected String contents;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id", foreignKey = 
  @ForeignKey(name = "fk_board_to_menu"))
  protected Menu menu;
}

@Entity
public class FirstBoard extends Board{
  // add additional fields
}
```

FirstBoard is an entity with some additional fields added to Board,
and I want to call FirstBoardController based on the menuId received as a parameter when calling 'getBoardList' method from BoardController.

```java
@Controller
public class BoardController {

    public Page<BoardDto> getBoardList(
            Pageable pageable,
            @RequestParam Integer menuId
    ) {
        return boardService.getBoardList(menuId, pageable);
    }
}

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FirstBoardController {

    private final FirstBoardService firstBoardService;

    public Page<FirstBoardDto> getBoardList(
            Pageable pageable,
            @RequestParam Integer menuId
    ) {
        return firstBoardService.getBoardList(menuId, pageable);
    }
}
```

I can't categorize posts via menuId in the usual way. This is because the DTO returned by getBoardList of FirstBoardController and the Service object used are also different from BoardController.

For example, if *board?menuId=1* is entered in the URL,
the getBoardList method of FirstBoardController is called, and if board?menuId=2 is entered in the URL, SecondBoardController (to be added later) is called.

The point is, I want to designate BoardController as the upper controller and treat the controller of the entity implemented by inheriting the value of Board Entity as menuId, a parameter of the function defined in BoardController.

After a little research, it seems that I can use HandlerMapping, but I have no idea how to do it.

Can you answer anything to me about this subject?

Comment: You should receive parameters in the same Controller and process them differently in the Service based on menuId.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use GetMapping#params/RequestMapping#params to achieve your goal.

```
@Controller
//Depends on your actual needs, the org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping#params may be using in here
public class BoardController {
    @GetMapping(params = "menuId=1") //when the menuId=1, it mapping match this method
    public Page<BoardDto> getBoardList(
            Pageable pageable,
            @RequestParam Integer menuId
    ) {
        return boardService.getBoardList(menuId, pageable);
    }
}

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FirstBoardController {

    private final FirstBoardService firstBoardService;
    @GetMapping(params = "menuId=2") //when the menuId=2, it mapping match this method
    public Page<FirstBoardDto> getBoardList(
            Pageable pageable,
            @RequestParam Integer menuId
    ) {
        return firstBoardService.getBoardList(menuId, pageable);
    }
}
```